Java, k consumer threads passive waiting instead of active waiting
I need to write a java method that doesn't have active waiting while having more consumer threads to run k runnables in parallel and when a runnable ends another runnable immediatly needs to run
This is my code:
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

public class ParallelExecutor {
    public static void executeInParallel(Runnable[] runnables, int K) {
        if (K <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't execute zero or less concurrent runnables");
        if (runnables == null || runnables.length == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must provide something to run");

        ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(K); // Extra space for end markers

        // Start the producer
        Thread producer = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                for (Runnable r : runnables) {
                    taskQueue.put(r); // Put a runnable in the queue
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });
        producer.start();

        // Start the consumer threads
        Thread[] consumers = new Thread[K];
        for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
            consumers[i] = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Runnable r;
                    while((r= taskQueue.take())!=null){
                            r.run();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); // Handle exceptions as needed
                }
            });
            consumers[i].start();
        }

        // Wait for the producer to finish
        try {
            producer.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        // Wait for all consumers to finish
        for (Thread consumer : consumers) {
            try {
                consumer.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example usage
        Runnable[] tasks = new Runnable[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
            final int index = i;
            tasks[i] = () -> {
                System.out.println("Task " + index + " is running.");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // Simulate work that takes 1 second
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                System.out.println("Task " + index + " is finished.");
            };
        }
        executeInParallel(tasks, 3); // Execute tasks in parallel, 3 at a time
    }
}

And there is  the code about the consumer threads
 // Start the consumer threads
        Thread[] consumers = new Thread[K];
        for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
            consumers[i] = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Runnable r;
                    while((r= taskQueue.take())!=null){
                            r.run();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); // Handle exceptions as needed
                }
            });
            consumers[i].start();
        }

my problem is the  while part because i think that's still active waiting and another problem is that if the effective number of threads<k the program enters a loop in the consumer threads while block, how can i change that little part of my code to have passive waiting?i dont wanna use other object inside the code if possible
I even tried to resolve the active wait doing  r=taskqueue.take(); but then my code just does k threads and stops.

ExecutorService
You seem to be re-inventing ExecutorService. That would be a waste of time. And that would be risky, as the executors framework is well-worn and reliable.
The Executors framework was added to Java 5 to relieve Java programmers of the burden of juggling threads. In modern Java, we rarely address the Thread class directly.
Define our example tasks.
Runnable task = ( ) -> System.out.println( Instant.now( ) );
Runnable[] tasks = Collections.nCopies( 10 , task ).toArray( Runnable[] :: new );

Obtain an ExecutorService implementation backed by a limited pool of threads.
final int MAX_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 3;
try (
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( MAX_THREAD_POOL_SIZE ) ;
)
{
    …
}

Notice the try-with-resources syntax to automatically close the ExecutorService after submitted tasks end.
Feed your tasks, your Runnable objects, to the executor service. For each task, you will get back a Future object to track its status, and success/failure.
List < ? extends Future < ? > > futures = Arrays.stream( tasks ).map( executorService :: submit ).toList( );
futures.forEach( future -> System.out.println( future.isDone( ) ) );

Entire code example:
System.out.println( "INFO - `main` start. " + Instant.now( ) );

Runnable task = ( ) -> System.out.println( Instant.now( ) );
Runnable[] tasks = Collections.nCopies( 10 , task ).toArray( Runnable[] :: new );

final int MAX_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 3;
try (
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( MAX_THREAD_POOL_SIZE ) ;
)
{
    List < ? extends Future < ? > > futures = Arrays.stream( tasks ).map( executorService :: submit ).toList( );
    futures.forEach( future -> System.out.println( future.isDone( ) ) );
    // Flow-of-control blocks here until all submitted tasks are done.
}
System.out.println( "INFO - `main` end. " + Instant.now( ) );

Notice how much simpler is this code.
When run:
INFO - `main` start. 2024-05-28T00:30:09.138059Z
2024-05-28T00:30:09.144181Z
2024-05-28T00:30:09.144235Z
2024-05-28T00:30:09.144258Z
2024-05-28T00:30:09.144450Z
2024-05-28T00:30:09.144544Z
2024-05-28T00:30:09.144468Z
2024-05-28T00:30:09.144484Z
2024-05-28T00:30:09.144581Z
2024-05-28T00:30:09.144649Z
2024-05-28T00:30:09.144740Z
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
INFO - `main` end. 2024-05-28T00:30:09.145357Z

Virtual threads
If your tasks are:

Not CPU-bound (they do involve some blocking such as for file I/O, network calls, database access, logging, etc.)
Not using long-running code within synchronized
Not using long-running native code (JNI, Foreign Function & Memory API, etc.)

… then consider using virtual threads for maximum performance.
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ; 

You may not need your limit of three threads any longer, with virtual threads. While one virtual thread is blocked, another takes its place on the CPU core. This, along with being light on memory usage, means conventional hardware can run many threads at a time, even millions may be reasonable.
If you do need to throttle the number of tasks running to protect scarce resources, use Semaphore with a desired number of permits.
Producer-Consumer
Your code is a bit difficult to understand. But you seem to have a one-to-one correspondence between producer tasks and consumer tasks. And you actually run your Producer code's run method from within the Consumer code. So there is no need for the queue. Just pass each producer object as a constructor argument to a consumer object.
In particular, I see no reason to use a Thread to populate your queue with producer objects. You could more efficiently just populate that queue directly in the calling thread. Further more, your comment Start the Producer is incorrect, as you are not starting the execution of the producer tasks; you are starting the populating of the queue of producer task objects.

i know about ExecutorService but i was asked to not use it

"i was asked to not use it" ? (A) You should mention such restrictions in the Question. (B) That is a silly ask. If this ask comes from a manager who does not understand modern Java programming, show them this Answer.

well i was asked to not use modern classes, i need to write  code for a really  old java system so it's a little hard for me

@Kishido: This doesn't make sense? The ArrayBlockingQueue you use, and the ExecutorService Basil is suggesting, were added to Java at the same time. That is, they are equally modern ...

can someone just write a solution that doesn't use that class?It's possible to do it without ExecutorService but i dont know how for now

Executors arrived in Java 5, two decades ago. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history
